# Prefetch metadata from video url

Tags: video, metadata, prefetch

I'm thinking about building a webpage that the user can provide a URL (like www.example.com/sample.mp4) and the server will download it for the user. But before the actual downloading starts, I would like the webpage to prefetch the metadata of that video so the user can know that's the one they want. Is there any standard/library for that with the only knowledge of the video URL? Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you type into Google.com : [**`"php" "mp4" metadata parser`**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22php%22+%22mp4%22+metadata+parser) maybe those results will help your research towards coding. We can only advice when your code is not working as intended

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried similar searches with Python, but just like the link you shared (if I don't miss any), those are libraries to get the metadata once you have the file on hand. I'm wondering if there's a standardized way to do it for a huge video file that can be only accessed by HTTP, without downloading the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a HTML5 video tag which advises the browser to load metadata only when the page loads for a given video. It is used like this:

```html
<video id="yourVideoID" controls preload="metadata">
  <source src="yourVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="youVideo.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

You can then have an event trigger when the metadata has loaded:

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("yourVideoID");
vid.onloadedmetadata = function() {
    //Do your work here 
};
```

One important caveat: the preload attribute is advisory only - browser do not have to do what it says (the logic is that videos are large and you may not want to have then automatically load or start).

Most browsers do follow it, but it may be worth experimenting to see if it meets your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Glad to know this and I think it would be very useful if I'm scrapping a web page. But currently, I'm working on raw URL like this [link](http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4) and there's no html file included at all.